# keep textbox value when page redirect to same page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have a page and i filled some text box values.
Then I check a radiobutton and a popup generate and through that I enter some more value in the respective popup  textbox fields.
Now when I close the popup the page is calling through a response.redirect and all the previously entered values get cleared.
I need to keep those value.
Please help on this point.

Comment: Use state management..

Comment: but the state management value get cleared when page get response.redirect.I have used view state.but no result

Comment: you can pass the values in QueryString or use Session..

Comment: Why are you calling a response.redirect?  It sounds like you want to do a simple post-back instead.

Comment: Is there any way that I can keep my control values even after response.redirect(Postback)